# I want to hide the shutdown menu on the GUI

Tags: 22.04

I want to hide the shutdown menu on the GUI.
I want to run it with settings such as Config instead of apps.

Execution environment: Ubuntu22.04, desktop PC

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Unfortunately, the question is somewhat unclear. What do you mean by "I want to run it with settings such as Config instead of apps"? 

Comment: When I look it up, I can find what to do with the GNOME configuration editor, but I want to run it in the configuration file.

Comment: It is possible to change Gnome configurations via the command line, but there is no single file that a person can use to configure everything 

Comment: Is it possible to change the Gnome settings from the command line to hide the power menu?

Comment: Perhaps [this Gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2917/bring-out-submenu-of-power-offlogout-button/) will give you what you need.

Comment: It looked like I needed to install gnome-software and ExtensionManager but ExtensionManager crashes when I try to find it in ExtensionManager. what is wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you're not running Ubuntu 22.04, but something else ...

Comment: My execution environment is Ubuntu22.04. Excuse me, but is there a different way than what you taught me?